# Proving $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} xf(x)=0$ if $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ converges.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f(x)$ be a monotone non-increasing function such that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ converges. Prove: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} xf(x)=0$. My question is, why can't I simply contradict any other possibility by using the Integral Limit Comparison Test with $1\over x$? I am, after all, to show that $f(x)=o(x)$ as $x\to \infty$. I really don't understand why monotony is crucial here. I could use some help.

Comment: $\int_0^b \sin(x)/x$ converges to $\pi/2$ but $x (\sin(x)/x) = \sin(x)$ does not converge to $0$. Can you see why limit comparison doesn't work?

Comment: nice question ..............+1

Comment: This lecturer's questions seem pretty, proportionally popular here... However, while getting ready for exams solving previous exams, his are the only ones that get me stuck for ages, and the same is relevant to the exam day. This is quite a conflict between encouraging pure theory and encouraging forward interest, if not success.

Comment: It would be nice if the non-increasing can be dropped, of course, the limit should be replaced by $\liminf$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume that $f$ is non-negative (this is justified; see the end of the post for the somewhat tedious details). If $\int_0^{\infty}f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ converges, then, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $x_0>0$ such that $y>x_0$ implies that $$\int_y^{\infty}f(t)\,\mathrm dt<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.\tag{1}$$ I will show that if $x>2x_0$, then $xf(x)<\varepsilon$, which will prove that claim that $\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)=0$.

Suppose that $x>2x_0$. Then, one has that
\begin{align*}
xf(x)=&\,2\frac{x}{2}f(x)=2\left(x-\frac{x}{2}\right)f(x)=2f(x)\int_{x/2}^x\,\mathrm dt=2\int_{x/2}^xf(x)\,\mathrm dt\\
\underset{\spadesuit}\leq&\,2\int_{x/2}^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt\leq2\int_{x/2}^{\infty}f(t)\,\mathrm dt\underset{\heartsuit}<2\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
In this chain of inequalities,

- $\spadesuit$ follows from the fact that $f$ is non-increasing, so that $f(x)\leq f(t)$ for all $t\in[x/2,x]$; and
- $\heartsuit$ follows from (1), given that $x/2>x_0$.

---

The convergence of $\int_0^{\infty} f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ and the monotonicity of $f$ necessarily imply that $f(t)\geq0$ for all $t\geq0$. To see this, suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $f(t_0)<0$ for some $t_0\geq 0$. Let
\begin{align*}
K\equiv&-f(t_0)>0.
\end{align*}
Let $M>0$ be an arbitrarily large positive number and choose some positive number $H$ sufficiently large so that $$H\geq\frac{t_0f(0)+M}{K}\tag{2}.$$
Finally, suppose that $x>t_0+H$. Then, one has that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=&\,\int_0^{t_0}f(t)\,\mathrm dt+\int_{t_0}^xf(t)\,\mathrm  dt\underset{\clubsuit}{\leq}t_0f(0)+(x-t_0)f(t_0)=t_0 f(0)-(x-t_0)K\\
<&\,t_0 f(0)-HK\leq t_0 f(0)-[t_0 f(0)+M]=-M,
\end{align*}
where $\clubsuit$ follows again from the fact that $f$ is non-increasing. Since $M$ can be arbitrarily large, it follows that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=-\infty,$$ which contradicts the convergence of $\int_0^{\infty} f(t)\,\mathrm dt$.

---

As the counterexamples in the comments reveal, monotonicity is indispensable. Indeed, I used them at two crucial steps: at $\spadesuit$ and $\clubsuit$.

Comment: We have the same basic idea, different implementations.

Comment: This is nice but I proved this using the fact that $xf(x)$ must be a decreasing function so if $ lim xf(x) = k \neq 0$ then $xf(x) > k$ then the contradiction follows from taking the integral. Is my argument valid? I posted it as the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$F(x)
=\int_0^x f(t) dt
$.
We are given that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)$
exists.
Call this limit $L$.

Suppose it is not true that
$\lim_{x \to \infty} xf(x)
= 0
$.
Then there is a $c > 0$
such that
$x f(x) > c$
for arbitrarily large $x$.

Suppose
$x_0 f(x_0) > c$
for $x_0$ large enough that
$\int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(t) dt
< d
$.
Choose an $x_1 > x_0$ such that
$x_1 f(x_1) > c$.
Since $f$ is monotone decreasing,
$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(t) dt
> (x_1-x_0)f(x_1)
> (x_1-x_0)(c/x_1)
= c(1-x_0/x_1)
$.
If we choose
$x_1 > 2 x_0$,
then
$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(t) dt
> c/2
$.

So we have
$d
>\int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(t) dt
>\int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(t) dt
>c/2
$.

But since
$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_{x}^{\infty} f(t) dt
=0
$,
we can choose $x_0$ large enough
so that $d$ is arbitrarily small.
In particular,
we can choose $d < c/2$,
which contradicts the
inequality above.

Therefore,
$\lim_{x \to \infty} xf(x)
= 0
$.

Comment: This is nice but I proved this using the fact that $xf(x)$ must be a decreasing function so if $ lim \ \ xf(x) = k \neq 0$ then $xf(x) > k$ then the contradiction follows from taking the integral. Is my argument valid? I posted it as the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There are counterexamples otherwise: $f(x)$ is $n$ if $n<x<n+1/(n^3)$, $f(x)$ is 0 otherwise. The integral exists, but $f(x)$ diverges.

Comment: $f$ is assumed non-increasing.

Answer (score 1):

without loss of generality one can assume that $f(0)=a$. Then $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=k=\int_0^af^{-1}(y)dy$ with first improper integral being type I and second type II. Since the second integral also converge, the assertion follows from $0<xf(x)<\int_0^{f(x)}f^{-1}(y)dy\to 0.$
(a picture might be helpful to see the simple geometric idea)