# Trouble Understanding Proof Integration Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, limits, improper-integrals

[image]

I'm somewhat struggling with this question, in terms of understanding what is going on.
I know proving that $f(x)=o(1/x)$ is the same (I believe) as proving that $\lim_{x\to\infty}xf(x)=0$.

I found this proof on Stackexchange: [image]

The problem is, I don't understand a part in the proof.  Why does$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\int_{\frac{t}{2}}^{t} f(x)\,dx=0$?  I don't understand where this comes from at all.
Questions why does the integrand go from $t/2$ to $t$? And why does it equal 0?

Comment: $\int_{t/2}^tf(x)dx<\int_{t/2}^\infty f(x)dx\overset{t\to\infty}{=}0$

Comment: See marty cohen (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13079/marty-cohen), Proving $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} xf(x)=0$ if $\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx$ converges., URL (version: 2015-08-16): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1398839

Comment: Thanks.  What is the motivative behind choosing t/2 and t for the bounds?

Comment: Try to recall the proof that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. At least one of those proofs takes the sum $\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} \ge \frac{n}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$. The same proof can be 'ported' to the integration case ($\int_t^{2t}$) and then taken in reverse (the integral converges, so those 'limited' integrals converge to zero). I think that is at least *some* motivation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle\int_{a}^{\infty}f(x)dx=L$, then for $\epsilon>0$, there is some $M$ such that $\left|\displaystyle\int_{a}^{u}f(x)dx-L\right|<\epsilon$ for all $u>M$. For all $t>2M$, then 
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{t/2}^{t}f(x)dx\right|&=\left|\int_{a}^{t}f(x)dx-L+L-\int_{a}^{t/2}dx\right|\\
&\leq\left|\int_{a}^{t}f(x)dx-L\right|+\left|\int_{a}^{t/2}f(x)dx-L\right|\\
&<2\epsilon,
\end{align*}
since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, the result follows.

Comment: I understand this but why does he specifically choose t/2 and t as his integrand bounds.  What is the motivative behind this?

Comment: You can choose any constant $C\in(0,1)$ with $Ct$ as the lower bound for the integral.

Comment: Thanks but why can you do this/what is the purpose?

Comment: Then the lenth $t-Ct=(1-C)t>0$, and in fact, $\displaystyle\int_{Ct}^{t}f(x)dx\geq\displaystyle\int_{Ct}^{t}f(t)dx=f(t)\int_{Ct}^{t}1dx=f(t)(t-Ct)=(1-C)f(t)t>0$ and we now use Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L= \int_a^{\infty}f(x) dx$ and $F(t)=\int_a^{t}f(x) dx$ . Then $F(t) \to L$ for $ t \to \infty$.

Since $\int_{t/2}^{t}f(x)dx=F(t)-F(t/2)$, we get

$\int_{t/2}^{t}f(x)dx \to L-L=0$ for $ t \to \infty$.