# Integration by parts with continuous random variables

Tags: integration, means

Show that for any continuous positive random variable
$X$ with $F(x) = F_X(x)$

we have
$$EX =\int_{0}^{\infty} (1 − F(x)) \text{ d}x\text{.}$$

[Hint: use integration by parts on $(1 − F(x)) · 1$.]

I have no idea how to use the hint, could someone help for this? Thanks

Comment: If you assume that $X$ has a density  (recall that the density is the derivative of the CDF), then $E[X] = \int_0^\infty x F'(x) dx$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected value as integral of survival function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642021/expected-value-as-integral-of-survival-function)

Comment: Are you forced to use integration by parts? If you are not, the question is a multiplicate of the site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_{(0,b]}x^aF(x)dx=-b^a(1-F(b))+a\int_{(0,b]}x^{a-1}(1-F(x))dx$$

If you need more hints feel free to ask.