# waiting time for two emails (probability)

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Emails come from two professors at the rate of 4/hour and 6/hour respectively.
What is the expected time I will have to wait until both the emails arrive?

In this question, am I supposed to find maximum time for (X,Y) where X represent time of arrival of email from professor A(say) and Y represents time of arrival of email from Professor B?

Comment: Yes, that is what you are supposed to find: the expected value of the maximum of the two exponentially distributed random variables.  (At least, that's the way I read the question.)

Comment: Ok, in that case, if I define Z (a new random variable) to be max(X,Y), then I found that Z is also exponentially distributed with rate 10/hour. What next, then?

Comment: No, the *minimum* should be exponentially distributed with rate $10$.  The maximum is not exponentially distributed.

Comment: Ok. Any hint on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: "$\max(X,Y)\le t$" is the same as "$X\le t$ and $Y\le t$". Therefore
$$
P(\max(X,Y)\le t)=P(X\le t,Y\le t)=P(X\le t)P(Y\le t),\tag1
$$
the last equality by (assumed) independence. Now you can deduce the density of $\max(X,Y)$ from (1), and then compute the expectation.

Another approach: use [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/642021/215011)
$$
E(T) = \int_0^\infty P(T>t)\,dt,
$$
which is valid for any nonnegative random variable $T$.

Comment: I am not sure about max(X,Y) >t means X>t and Y>t. For example, Y>t but X<t still gives us max(X,Y)>t, right?

Comment: @Ufomammut Right! I had my inequality reversed. Fixed.