# Calculation of Mean of a r.v using an inequality

Tags: probability

I saw once saw it somewhere used that for a nonnegative rv $X$ ,
$$  E(X) = \int_0^\infty Pr(X \geq t).$$
Could someone kindly explain .Or Am I wrong?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/642021/expected-value-as-integral-of-survival-function

Comment: Sure..that does ..thank you all of you